# Can I use Wordpress plugins/addons in Bootstrap themes?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I plan to create a site on Bootstrap. I want to use Wordpress plugins/addons in it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure you can , if you wanted to build wordpress site on bootstrap take a look at this this is a good starter theme based on bootstrap3 http://roots.io/starter-theme/